# Set main checkbox true if all sbu checkbox are true

Tags: javascript

I have a table having two type of rows (main row and sub row). 
Row id of main row is "mainRow" + prId(Attribute of tr).
Row id of sub row is "subRow" + prId(Attribute of tr) + rowNo.

What i have to do is that if all checkbox of sub rows are checked then checkbox of main row must be checked. Can someone help me out.

```
<tr id="mainRow2" prId = "2"><td><input type="checkbox" id="main0" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow2_1" prId = "2"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow2_1_1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow2_2" prId = "2"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow2_2_1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow2_3" prId = "2"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow2_3_1" ></td></tr>

<tr id="mainRow5" prId = "5"><td><input type="checkbox" id="main1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow5_1" prId = "5"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow5_1_1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow5_2" prId = "5"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow5_2_1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow5_3" prId = "5"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow5_3_1" ></td></tr>
    <tr id="subRow5_4" prId = "5"><td><input type="checkbox" id="subRow5_4_1" ></td></tr>
```

Comment: I'd start by putting each set of rows in a separate table section using a tbody element. Then put a click listener on each tbody or the table. If it gets a click from a checkbox, it looks at the inputs in the related table section and if all the subs are checked, checks the main checkbox for that set. Otherwise, it unchecks the main checkbox. If the main checkbox is checked by the user, you might want to check all the sub checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following jQuery code to your page (make sure you include the jQuery script on your page).

Although your organization of checkboxes is wrong and you should work on reorganizing the table.

```
$('input').change(function() {

  $("tr[id^='mainRow']").each(function(i,v){
    var id = $(v).attr('id');
    id = id.split('mainRow')[1];
    var subs = $("input[id^='subRow"+id+"']");
    var checkedSubs = $("input[id^='subRow"+id+"']:checked");
    console.log(checkedSubs.length);

    if(subs.length == checkedSubs.length)
      $('input',v).attr('checked',true);
    else
      $('input',v).attr('checked',false);
  });

});
```

[Live example here.](http://jsbin.com/acolozU/1/edit?html,js,output)